# Jsoup: Performance of top-level select() vs. inner-level select()

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

My understanding is that once a document is loaded into Jsoup, using `Jsoup.parse()`, no parsing is required again as a neatly hierarchical tree is ready for programmer's use.

But what I am not sure whether top-level select() is more costly than inner-level select().

For example, if we have a `<p>` buried inside many nested `<div>`s, and that `<p>`'s parent is already available in the program, will there be *any* performance difference between:

```
document.select("p.pclass")
```

and

```
pImediateParent.select("p.pclass")
```

?

How does that work in Jsoup?

**UPDATE:** Based on the answer below, I understand that both `document.select()` and `pImediateParent.select()` use the [same exact static method](http://massapi.com/source/jsoup-1.6.1-sources/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.java.html), just with a different root as the second parameter:

```
public Elements select(String query) {
    return Selector.select(query, this);
}
```

Which [translates into](http://massapi.com/source/jsoup-1.6.1-sources/org/jsoup/select/Selector.java.html):

```
/**
 * Find elements matching selector.
 *
 * @param query CSS selector
 * @param root  root element to descend into
 * @return matching elements, empty if not
 */
public static Elements select(String query, Element root) {
    return new Selector(query, root).select();
}
```

I am not surprised, but the question now is how does that `query` work? Does it iterate to find the queried element? Is it a random access (as in hash table) query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be faster if you use the intermediate parent. If you check the Jsoup source code, you'll see that [`Element#select()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) actually delegates to the [`Selector#select()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html#select%28java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.nodes.Element%29) method with the `Element` itself as 2nd argument. Now, the javadoc of that method says:

> ### select
>
> ```
> public static Elements select(String query, Element root)
> ```
>
> Find elements matching selector.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - query - CSS selector
> - root - root element to descend into
>
> #### Returns:
>
> matching elements, empty if not

Note the description of the `root` parameter. So yes, it definitely makes difference. Not shocking, but there is *some* difference.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question above to add references to the source code. Now the question is on the [ROI](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roi) of "caching" an intermediate parent. If it's going to be used as a query's root many times in a loop (vs. using document as a root), that could actually boost performance, right?

Comment: Yes, but this is a microboost rather than a megaboost. Or you must be traversing an extraordinary large HTML document of >10MB or something. Measuring (profiling) is knowing.